# Maven generate-source ALWAYS Successful

Tags: maven

I am trying to run a ant task in maven generate-sources phase.

However, after many non productive "successes" i've realised, that the build always succeeds regardless of anything i enter.

Here is the plugin config for the pom.xml of my module.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <fail message="Something wrong here."/>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

It still succeeds. If i place a bad ant file. Still succeeds.

Does anyone know what i could be doing wrong here?

The Compile/Clean/Install/Deploy phases all work fine. Just "generate-source" doesnt work at all.

My settings.xml file only contains Repo information
Thanks for any advice

**Edit:**

I've been able to narrow the error down a little.

```
<configuration>
<target>
<echo message="hello ant, from Maven!"/>
<echo>Maybe this will work?</echo>
</target>
</configuration>
```

If place that within the configuration of the plugin, Not in the nested configuration in the execution tag. and run "mvn antrun:run" I see the echos. However If i place it in the nested configuration in the execution element, it doesnt show... Is there some link missing between my mvn goal and the antrun instruction?

I don't get it. The same configuration runs outside of the executions/execution tags, but not within.

Comment: Consider replacing `<tasks>` with `<target>`, as `<tasks>` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** **Solution** **Solution**
AHHH I found it!
In my pom.xml I had all my 'plugins''plugin' configured under the 'pluginManagement' .. This 'pluginManagement' configures the plugins not for this project, but for all children project. Effectively a parent default config file for all children implementing the plugin.. I simply removed the 'pluginManagement' tags and it works...

Thank heavens. I've been looking at this for a full day...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<failOnError>false</failOnError>` to the execution.

Per the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html), this parameter "specifies whether a failure in the ant build leads to a failure of the Maven build. If this value is 'true', the Maven build will proceed even if the ant build fails. If it is 'false', then the Maven build fails if the ant build fails."

This is counterintuitive to me.  I would think that the default value of "true" would cause the Maven build to fail if the ant build failed, but that isn't what the docs appear to be saying.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately still no Joy. I've also replaced "task" with "target" and it still always passes.